# Django: how to correctly pass an URL in include template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In two different templates, I have two blocks almost identical, only the url is different:

#### template1.html

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="{% url 'bo:article-list' %}" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary btn-sm"
       role="button">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Annuler
    </a>
</div>
```

#### template2.html

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary btn-sm"
       role="button">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Annuler
    </a>
</div>
```

I'd like to make this dry, creating a template, and making an include then.
For example:

#### _cancel.html

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<a href="{{ cancel_url }}" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary btn-sm"
   role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Annuler
</a>
```

For **template2.html**, it will work with:

```
{% include 'includes/_cancel.html' with cancel_url=article.get_absolute_url %}
```

But what about **template1.html** ?
This obviously does NOT work :

```
{% include 'includes/_cancel.html' with cancel_url={% url 'bo:article-list' %}
```

I guess there is a trick. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `url` tag can be used to save its result to a context variable by using [`as`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

```
{% url 'bo:article-list' as cancel_url %}
```

and you can now pass this into your include tag.